# Como pasar mock desde test a controlador en Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony3

estoy intentando testear un controlador que utiliza el método *find* y no se conseguia mockear el entity manager. Lo logré pasando los mocks con el método request utilizando la funcion returnURL. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo. Muchas Gracias. A continuación el codigo del test y la clase controlador a testear.

```
public function setUp()
{
parent::setUp();

$this->client = static::createClient();
$this->peopleManager = $this->getMockBuilder(PeopleManager::class)
    ->setMethods(['createPerson','peopleUpdate', 'peopleDelete', 
    'peopleRead'])
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

 $this->repository = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
   ->disableOriginalConstructor()
   ->getMock();

$this->em = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManager::class)
   ->disableOriginalConstructor()
   ->getMock();

$this->client->getContainer()->set('people.manager', $this->peopleManager);
}

public function returnURL($secc)
{
   return $this->client->request('POST', '/api/' . $secc, array('array' => array([
   "name"=>"Juan",
   "surname"=>"Hernandez",
   "secondSurname"=>"Macias",
   "nationality"=>null,
   "birthday"=>null,
   "identityCard"=> "12345678a",
   "identityCardType"=> null
 ]),
    'em' => $this->em,
    'repository' => $this->repository
));
}

public function test_update_person_action()
{
$persona= $this->returnPerson();
$personaSinActualizar = $this->returnPeople('210', 'Antonio', 'Juan', 'A', '11111111Y');
$this->peopleManager->method('peopleUpdate')->will($this->returnValue($persona));

$this->repository->expects($this->exactly(1))->method('find')->will($this->returnValue($personaSinActualizar));
$this->em->expects($this->exactly(1))->method('getRepository')->will($this->returnValue($this->repository));

$this->returnURL('updateperson/210');
$content = json_decode($this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
$testValues = array
(
    '212',
    'Juan',
    'Hernandez',
    'Macias',
    '12345678a'
);
$contador=0;
foreach ($content as $partContent)
{
    $this->assertEquals($testValues[$contador], $partContent);
    $contador++;
}
}




class RestController extends FOSRestController
{
private $repository;
private $em;

public function updatePersonAction($id, Request $request)
{
$this->em = $request->request->get('em');
$this->repository = $request->request->get('repository');

$this->repository = $this->em->getRepository('GeneralBundle:People');
$person= $this->repository->find($id);
if($person)
{
    $data = $request->request->get('array');
    $createdPeople = array();
    $UpdatedPerson = "";
    foreach($data as $content)
    {
        $UpdatedPerson = $this->get('people.manager')->peopleUpdate(
            $person,
            $content['name'],
            $content['surname'],
            $content['secondSurname'],
            $content['nationality'],
            $content['birthday'],
            $content['identityCard'],
            $content['identityCardType']
        );
        array_push($createdPeople, $person);
    }
    $serializedEntity = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($UpdatedPerson, 'json');
    return new Response($serializedEntity);
} else {
    $serializedEntity = $this->get('serializer')->serialize('Doesn\'t exists any person with this id', 'json');
    return new Response($serializedEntity);
}
}
```

Buenas, estoy intentando testear un controlador que utiliza el método *find* y no se conseguia mockear el entity manager. Lo logré pasando los mocks con el método request utilizando la funcion returnURL. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo. Muchas Gracias. A continuación el codigo del test y la clase controlador a testear.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro q tu controlador funcione bien fuera del test por que le estas pasando dos servicios en el request q solo son construidos en el test:

```
$this->em = $request->request->get('em');
$this->repository = $request->request->get('repository');
```

en una solicitud normal eso no funcionaria.

Como mismo seteas el people.manager puedes hacer:

```
$this->getContainer()->set('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
```

para sobreescribir con el mock.

El controller no debe construirse esperando algo q debe o no estar en los tests, ni poner condiciones para que funcionen los tests. Mas bien el test debe usar lo q hay en el controller o la clase que se esta testeando. Por otro lado nunca esta de mas hacer lo mas sencillo posible las clases para facilitar los tests.